# Understanding the behaviour of parametrizing a Generic with None

Tags: python, python-typing

I am writing a fuzzer for a strongly-typed assembly-like language and I am relying on the Python typing system to parametrize the typing of the underlying generated language. I then inspect the Python types at runtime in order to dynamically generate the correct parametrization of the target fuzzed language.

I have a case where I parametrize a `Generic[T, Optional[S]]` and as the `Optional` hints, the S will sometimes be `None`. Let's take the following minimal example of class structure:

```py
class Signed:
    ...

class Unsigned:
    ...

class OpTypeInt:
    ...

class OpTypeFloat:
    ...

class LogicalOperator(Generic[T, S]):
    ...

class BinaryLogicalOperatorFuzzMixin:
    ...

class BinaryLogicalOperator(LogicalOperator[T, Optional[S]]):
    ...

# "less than" OpCode parametrized for floats
class OpFLessThan(
    BinaryLogicalOperatorFuzzMixin, BinaryLogicalOperator[OpTypeFloat, None]
):
    ...

# "less than" OpCode parametrized for unsigned integers
class OpULessThan(
    BinaryLogicalOperatorFuzzMixin, BinaryLogicalOperator[OpTypeInt, Unsigned]
):
    ...

# "less than" OpCode parametrized for signed integers
class OpSLessThan(
    BinaryLogicalOperatorFuzzMixin, BinaryLogicalOperator[OpTypeInt, Signed]
):
    ...
```

Now during the runtime of the program, I will inspect these types to dictate the behaviour of the fuzzer. The inspection code looks like this:

```py
base_type, type_constraint = get_args(OpSLessThan.__orig_bases__[1])
# OpSLessThan is a BinaryLogicalOperator[OpTypeInt, Signed]

print(base_type, type_constraint)
# <class '__main__.OpTypeInt'> <class '__main__.Signed'>

print(
    isinstance(type_constraint, Signed),
    type(type_constraint) == type(Signed),
    type(type_constraint) == Signed,
    type_constraint == type(Signed),
)
# False True False False

base_type, type_constraint = get_args(OpILessThan.__orig_bases__[1])
# OpILessThan is a BinaryLogicalOperator[OpTypeInt, None]

print(base_type, type_constraint)
# <class '__main__.OpTypeInt'> <class 'NoneType'>

print(
    isinstance(type_constraint, NoneType),
    type(type_constraint) == type(None),
    type(type_constraint) == None,
    type_constraint == type(None),
    type_constraint is None,
)
# False False False True False  huh?
```

Why is `type(type_constraint) == type(Signed)` a valid way of checking that the class has `Signed` as a base but isn't a valid way of checking for `None`? Why does `None` require to check for `type_constraint == type(None)`?

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

Use [`issubclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#issubclass):

```py
base_type, type_constraint = get_args(OpFLessThan.__orig_bases__[1])
# OpILessThan is a BinaryLogicalOperator[OpTypeInt, None]

print(base_type, type_constraint)
# <class '__main__.OpTypeInt'> <class 'NoneType'>

print(issubclass(type_constraint, NoneType))
# True
```

---

`type(a_class) == type(Signed)` is not a valid way of checking that the class has `Signed` as a base.

It evaluates to `True` because `type(<a class>)` is `type`, hence `type == type` produces `True`.

```py
>>> type(Signed)
<class 'type'>
```

This holds for every class in `Python`, including the `type` class itself:

```py
>>> type(type)
<class 'type'>
```

`type(None) != type(a_class)` because `None` is an object, not a class, hence `type(None) == NoneType`.